# How to fix Facebook has detected MyAppName isn't using a secure connection to transfer information

Tags: python, django, facebook-login

I am trying to implement facebook social Oauth login on my Django app but I am faced with the below error.

I have tried changing my from http to **https** on **Valid OAuth Redirect URIs**.

I am trying to redirect to this Url **mysite.com:8000/social-auth/complete/facebook/**  but it is given me the below error response.

[image]

I also tried https://localhost url and it seems to work for fine.